# How to run the servlet test by using HttpUnit servlet runner? Problems in Starting up with ServletUnit?

Tags: java, http-unit

I was planning to unit test my Servlet through ServletUnit and ran across some problems :
- As a starting point, we are supposed to create a ServletRunner object. One of the constructors expects File object with web.xml file. I provide the full path of my web.xml file but somehow it ignores the path provided and searches at the top level folder. The code-snippet and error message is below:

**Code Snippet**

```
    ServletRunner sr = new ServletRunner(new File("* C:/eclipse-workspaces/pocs/lms-csd/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml*")); 
ServletUnitClient sc = sr.newClient(); 
 WebRequest request = new PostMethodWebRequest("path to be specified" ); request.setParameter( "userId", "test" );
 request.setParameter( "password", "csd" );
  WebResponse response = sc.getResponse(request);
  String text = response.getText();
```

Assert.assertTrue(text.contains("Welcome to Leave Management System"));

**stack trace**

```
    com.meterware.httpunit.HttpInternalErrorException:
 Error on HTTP request: 500 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: * C:\eclipse-workspaces\pocs\lms-csd\WEB-INF\web.xml* 
(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

[http://localhost/login]    - Why does the system keep on looking at the folder structure to be .../WEB-INF/web.xml.
 Mine is a maven project and I would not like to change the structure of the project to adapt this way. How can I make ServletRunner class to read from a specified folder ?   - In the Servlet code, 
I use the following code :

```
 String result = null if (someCondition) result = "/welcome.jsp"; } else { logger.warn("Password Validation failed"); request.setAttribute("failedlogin", new Boolean(true)); result = "/index.jsp"; } } RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(result); requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Again ServletUnit expects welcome.jsp to be at root foler, though jsp files are present at .../src/main/webapp/ folder. Again how can ServletUnit be told about the target folder location ?

Many thanks in advance.

Best Regards
M.SuriNaidu

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing I do. This is a facsimile of the base class of my servlet tests. In this case I pass the relative path of the web.xml file as it exists in my source tree. I run these tests from ant and eclipse.

```
abstract public class ServletTestCase {

    protected ServletRunner       m_runner;
    protected ServletUnitClient   m_client;
    protected String              m_userAgent = "something/1.0";

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        initHttpUnit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        shutdownHttpUnit();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    protected void initHttpUnit() throws IOException, SAXException {
        shutdownHttpUnit();

        // We are expecting UTF-8 character handling in URLs, make it the default
        HttpUnitOptions.setDefaultCharacterSet("UTF-8");

        // Find the servlet's web.xml file and use it to init servletunit
        File file = new File("tests/web.xml"));
        m_runner = new ServletRunner(file);
        m_client = m_runner.newClient();
        m_client.getClientProperties().setUserAgent(m_userAgent);
    }

    protected void shutdownHttpUnit() {
        if (m_runner != null) {
            m_runner.shutDown();
        }
        m_client = null;
        m_runner = null;
    }
}
```